# Error displaying custom field in Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, files

I'm trying to create a lightning component that will display the list of related Files on a record, as well as their metadata.

My code currently pulls the file names, file type, and description. However, when I try to call the custom field "Document_Type__c" in the apex, I get the error "No such column on entity 'ContentDocument'.

Controller:

```
({  
   doInit:function(component,event,helper){  
     var action = component.get("c.getFiles");  
     action.setParams({  
       "recordId":component.get("v.recordId")  
     });      
     action.setCallback(this,function(response){  
       var state = response.getState();  
       if(state=='SUCCESS'){  
         var result = response.getReturnValue();  
         console.log('result: ' +result);  
         component.set("v.files",result);  
       }  
     });  
     $A.enqueueAction(action);  
   } ,  
   //Open File onclick event  
   OpenFile :function(component,event,helper){  
     var rec_id = event.currentTarget.id;  
     $A.get('e.lightning:openFiles').fire({ //Lightning Openfiles event  
       recordIds: [rec_id] //file id  
     });  
   },  

 })
```

Apex:

```
public class SimplyfyFilesCntrl {  
   @AuraEnabled  
   public static List<ContentDocument> getFiles(string recordId){  
     List<ContentDocument> DocumentList = new List<ContentDocument>();  
     Set<Id> documentIds = new Set<Id>();  //store file ids
     List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl=[select id,LinkedEntityId,ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId=:recordId];  
     for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:cdl){  
       documentIds.add(cdLink.ContentDocumentId);  // Document ids
     }      
     DocumentList = [select Id,Title,FileType,ContentSize,Description from ContentDocument where id IN: documentIds];  
     return DocumentList;  
   }  

 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that custom field is not on the `ContentVersion` object instead?

Comment: Ah, this is it. Thank you! Is it possible to add my custom field to ContentDocument rather than ContentVersion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's rather buried in the documentation, if you check out the [object reference for `ContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm), you'll find

> Content metadata, such as tags, custom fields, and content owners are tracked at the version level rather than at the document level.

Likewise at [Customize Content Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=content_fields.htm&type=5):

> To create, modify, and delete Salesforce CRM Content custom fields for categorizing and defining your content, go to the object management settings for content. If you're using Lightning Experience, go to the Object Manager, select Content Version, then scroll to the fields area. If you're using Salesforce Classic, enter Salesforce Files in the Quick Find box, then select Fields.

Hence, custom fields for Content go on the `ContentVersion` object, not on `ContentDocument`.